# YouTube Data API v3 comment list

Tags: json, youtube-api

I am using a YouTube V3.0 API call to download a JSON feed of information for a particular YouTube channel (e.g: the Apple YouTube channel).

now, i've manage to have the videos list and all, but i would also like, if possible, to have the comments, or some of them, for the videos. I have searched on the channels->list documentation and video-list and even video->search, but without success.

anyone can give me a hand, if this is possible of course.

thanks in advance :)

J.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all comments on a YouTube video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965856/how-to-get-all-comments-on-a-youtube-video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not available in the API version 3, yet. Only in version 2.
There is already an enhancement request filed here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5046

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not sure if this will help you any, but I actually use the below URL to gather comments from a specific video using the YouTube API V3.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=**YOUR_KEY**&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet&videoId=**YOUTUBEVIDEOID**&maxResults=50
```

Hopefully this can assist you with what your trying to do if your still trying to do it.