# rselenium | get youtube page source

Tags: r, selenium, youtube, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

Why is the page source of youtube.com not scrapeable?

I tried the following (using phantomjs as well as chrome with a selenium server)

```
library(RSelenium)
pJS <- phantom(pjs_cmd = ...)
Sys.sleep(5) # give the binary a moment
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.youtube.com/")
remDr$getTitle()[[1]] # [1] "YouTube"
remDr$getPageSource()
```

Returns:

```
Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an issue with encoding. Use the dev version for now until the next version is released to CRAN:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that the problem is most probably with encoding.

For instance, such problem seems to appear on [nasa.gov](http://nasa.gov) website only on topic pages related to American-Russian space collaboration (which suggests that it is due to cyrillic characters in webpages content).

I solved the problem by using deprecated `Relenium` where `RSelenium` fails. To make `Relenium` run smoothly on `Ubuntu 16.04` I had to install `Firefox 25.0` and configure it in a way to prevent any updates. The other issue during set up was to properly install `rJava`, which can fail due to lack of environment variables with proper paths to Java libraries.

System configuration is as follows:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

relenium_0.3.0; seleniumJars_2.41.0; rJava_0.9-8; RSelenium_1.3.5
```

Below is an example of a page that can be scraped with Relenium but not with release version of RSelenium:

```
link = "http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition14/index.html"
```

RSelenium solution fails (with Firefox of version either `34.0.5`, or `25.0`, no matter):

```
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(link)
doc = unlist(remDr$getPageSource())
```

Result: **"Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input"**

While Relenium is ok with it:

```
 relenium_browser <- firefoxClass$new()
 relenium_browser$get(link)
 doc = unlist(relenium_browser$getPageSource())
 doc = read_html(doc)
```

Comment: There is an issue with firefox 47 and selenium. There is a released firefox 47.01 but it seems not available for ubuntu. You can install firefox 48 which should work with the current version of RSelenium. See https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/47.0.1/releasenotes/