# How to get a specific comment of a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Does anyone have any clue how to a specific comment on a YouTube video? For example the first one, or the last one and etc.
I tried looking into the YouTube API but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all comments on a YouTube video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965856/how-to-get-all-comments-on-a-youtube-video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can see is [Comments: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) which returns a list of comment resources.  I don't think you can get just a single one, I suspect you will need to get them all then search them yourself locally.

There also doesn't appear to be any search type method with the YouTube api under [standard parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/standard_parameters). So I think you are going to be stuck getting them all.